# Is jQuery needed in implementing AngularJS-strap?

Tags: angular-strap

AngularJS-strap modal didn't work, if I would not include jQuery plugins.

I use manual initialization in AngularJS '`AngularJS.Bootstrap()`'.

But when I try to execute `modal()`, I always have this error:

-- If I include jQuery:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element 'document'

Uncaught TypeError: el.focus is not a function
```

-- If I will not include jQuery
 modal or AngularJS-strap won't work due to this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
```

Answer (score -1):

RTFM!

> With no external dependency except the Bootstrap CSS styles,
>   AngularStrap is light and fast. It has been built from the ground up
>   to leverage ngAnimate!

Need to implement, shim dependecies for angular-strap.tpl.js.